# ._ .DS_store files and so on when syncronizing cloud drive services

Tags: macos, finder, file, dropbox, metadata

Is there a way to prevent Dropbox, or any other cloud service, from synchronizing those ._ and .DS_store files, although they exist in the Dropbox folder?

Comment: I'm not seeing a question here.

Comment: using *defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores -bool TRUE* in the terminal does this for shared network drives; I do not use dropbox, but maybe you like to check? Which version of MacOS? Which version of Dropbox?